# Extracting ragged vectors to construct even array in R

Tags: r

I have a series of fisheries catch-at-age proportions for a number of given years (1988 - 2012), extracted from a larger file using 'recast' in R 2.15.3. These are currently stored in a data frame with the structure:

```
 YEAR AGE AGE_x AGE_freq  proportion
 1988   9     9        2 0.004273504
 1988  10    10        2 0.004273504
 1988  11    11        7 0.014957265
 1988  12    12        7 0.014957265
 1988  13    13        3 0.006410256
 1988  14    14        1 0.002136752
 1988  15    15        1 0.002136752
 1988  16    16        4 0.008547009
 1988  17    17        1 0.002136752
 1988  18    18        4 0.008547009
```

The sum of all proportions for any given year = 1. All ages, however, are not present for all years; for any given year, there are ages for which no fish were observed, and therefore the values for AGE do not necessarily match between years, and the PROPORTION vectors are of different lengths.

I am trying to construct an even array ordered by YEAR and AGE,populated by PROPORTION, for which missing ages are filled in with NA markers (or 0 - it doesn't matter) to produce:

```
        AGE             
YEAR    8          9          10        11         12
1988    0          0.0043     0.0043    0.0149     0.0149
1989    0.01415    0.0141     0.0123    0          0
1990    0          0.0213     0.0149    0          0.0064
```

I've experimented with applications of recast, rbind, array subsetting, loops, and merge, but haven't been able to find the correct syntax.

Thanks so much!!

Comment: This should be an extremely simple application of `dcast`: `dcast(dat,YEAR~AGE,fun.aggregate = sum,value.var = "proportion")`. But you should really clean up your question so that your expected output actually makes sense given your example data.

Comment: An alternative: `as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(proportion ~ YEAR + AGE, data=dat))`

Comment: 'dcast' worked very nicely - thank you! I wasn't aware of that function.